# java socket not accepting byte array

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a simple socket program as shown below. I want to send a byte array to a server socket and readi it at the server end. 
This is the server

```
package com.java;

//File Name GreetingServer.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingsServer extends Thread
{
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public GreetingsServer(int port) throws IOException
{
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
}

public void run()
{
   while(true)
   {
      try
      {
          System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
         serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
         Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
               + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         DataInputStream in =
               new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
         System.out.println("--"+ server.getReceiveBufferSize());
         byte[] b1 = new byte[4] ;
         int i =in.read(b1);
         System.out.println("i = " + i  + "b1 = " +b1);
        /* DataOutputStream out =
              new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
         out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
           + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");*/
         server.close();
      }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
      {
         System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
         break;
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         break;
      }
   }
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   try
   {
      Thread t = new GreetingsServer(port);
      t.start();
   }catch(IOException e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
```

This is the client

```
package com.java;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String serverName = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         byte[] b = {1,2,3,4};
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
         /*BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outToServer);*/
         System.out.println("**" + b);  
         out.write(b);
         /*out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());*/

         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

The output I get is this for the server.

```
Waiting for client on port 6066...
Just connected to /127.0.0.1:52349
--65536
i = 4b1 = [B@48270664
Waiting for client on port 6066...
Socket timed out!
```

There two things wrong. The first is that the bytearray is not coming entirely to the server. And secondly the server is calling thread twice.

Any input will be helpful. Please let me know if anyone finds a problem!

Comment: if you change System.out.println("i = " + i  + "b1 = " +b1);
 with System.out.println("i = " + i  + "b1 = " +b1.toString()); you'll see your first problem doesn't exists

Comment: @wxyz. Yup. The fact that i is 4 is already a good sign... You may need something like Arrays.toString(b1) though. ... + b1) is already the same as ... + b1.toString())

Comment: Stupid mistake!!! I am getting the bytearray. Any reason for the two threads executing?

Comment: @Mad Physicist, you're right, thanks for clarifying. Also, there are no 2 threads, but a while loop which awaits for connections and runs on timeout after a while...You should create a new thread for each client.

Comment: Note for future readers: there was a `SocketTimeout` due to the timeout on the `ServerSocket`, which caused the 'Socket timed out!' condition.

Comment: thats right. about the server timeout. What can i do to create threads per client? check the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't what is being sent/received but rather how you're trying to output it to the console.

Arrays don't override `toString()`. In your server you have:

```
System.out.println("i = " + i  + "b1 = " +b1);
```

The output of `b1.toString()` is the default from `Object.toString()` which as noted in the Javdoc for `Object` is:

> a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

You need to use `Arrays.toString(b1)` to get a String that shows the actual bytes in that array as `[ x, x, x ,x ]` (where each `x` is the numeric value of the byte)